# Group of proposed duplicates: Threading and Listability

Tags: discussion, questions, site-organization, clean-up

There is is a group of similar questions some of which I believe need to be marked as duplicates.
Before I highhandedly close according to my own judgement I'd like to give the community a chance to speak.  Also, since this is an oft-covered topic it is quite likely that there are more questions that should be considered part of this group and I ask for help identifying them.

These are what I have found so far, oldest first:

- [Equating matrices (or higher order tensors) element-wise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/)
- [How to thread a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4004/121)
- [Thread a function over a list and with a non-atomic 2nd parameter?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/)
- [Thread over list in different levels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/121)
- [Thread over a nested list top to bottom until non-list elements are found](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17291/)
- [Elementwise join](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17400/121)
- [given n lists, get list of applications of function to n-tuples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23333/121)
- [How can I make threading more flexible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23395/)
- [How to combine elements of two matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31238/121)

Some of these are clearly not duplicates of another; I am *not* suggesting equivalence between all of these.  Rather, I believe that there *is* duplication within the group and I'm putting them all up for the community to look at.

Comment: Related to those Q&A's is [correct way to map a function on entries down the pages in a 3D matrix?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29856/4330)

Comment: I trust your judgement, as I'm getting of seeing lists thread before my eyes. I feel it is hard to improve the situation, which makes me sad. Titles like: How to thread a list make me sad. I would make it into something like "how to transform similar to Thread".. But ah my mind gets so stuck on meta subjects.

Comment: I agree that [17381](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17381/4330) is a duplicate of [4004](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4004/4330).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom LOL!!! I almost died laughing... 4330 is _your_ user ID, not the post ID (this is found immediately after the `/q/`). And of course, you're a duplicate of yourself :P

Comment: @rm-rf :P don't mind my clone being silly ;)

Comment: @Jacob Indeed it is, but 4004 adds an unusual complication; 17381 is the more natural.  I'm still working out how to handle that.